# beaglebone blackにおけるGPIO番号

Tags: linux

beaglebone blackにおけるS2ボタン(user/boot button)のGPIO番号およびレジスタのベースアドレスなどはどのように調べるのでしょうか。
PINのgpioの情報はたくさんあるのですが、S2ボタンについては情報がありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beaglebone blackを触ったことがないのでドキュメントからの推測です。
まず[BeagleBone Black System Reference Manual](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/BBB_SRM.pdf)を見ます。

**6.7.1 Boot Configuration Design** の配線を見ると `S2` は `LCD_DATA2` に接続されています。
これは`gpio2[8]`に相当するようですね。

レジスタについてはリファレンスには見当たらなかったのですが、[このサイト](http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/beaglebone-black/step04-gpio/)によれば、
`LCD_DATA2`のRegister Offsetは`44E018A8` となっています。